# ctrl + mouse wheel to zoom not working

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

On https://wp.veloinfanger.ch/touren/touren-uebersicht/ I have a Google Map embedded with gesture mode "cooperative". Unfortunately, the map not only zooms when the ctrl key is pressed but also when I scroll without pressing the ctrl key. On the other side, moving the map on touch devices only works with two fingers - as intended in cooperative mode.

The page was made using latest WordPress version 4.9.4.

Any ideas why the cooperative mode is not working on mouse wheel?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `div#cmmrm-route-index-map-canvas-XXXXXXXXX` out of its parent `div.cmmrm-route-map-canvas-outer`. Then it should work

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I have tested this without success. Therefore I changed the implementation so that the zoom via mousewheel is only activated after a click on the map.